# putting check to check some predetermined values and excute the buisness logic

Tags: java

I have an object ar which contains mainy method so one of the method is getrookic() like as shown below..

```
ar.getrookic()
```

now its return type is String

now it return values like 23, 34 like these....

now i have to put an condition where in advance i know that i have to do some logic
when this methods will return the value 66,77,64

so what shall i put in if check...

```
if (!ar.getrookic().equals(66) ||!ar.getrookic().equals(77) || !ar.getrookic().equals(64))
{

//do some logic
}
```

please advise it is correct approach..!

Comment: If that method's return type is `String`, why are you trying to perform equals on a value that will never be equivalent (i.e. you're comparing `String` to `Integer`)?

Comment: Does it return 66,77,64 as 1 string? i.e "66,77,64"?

Comment: try `Interger.parseInt(ar.getrookic().trim()) == 66`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be performing not on your `String` equality testing. If `ar.getrookic()` returns a `String` then you need to test `String` equality. If your function actually performs work then you should save the first reference -

```
String str = ar.getrookic();
if (str.equals("66") || str.equals("77") || str.equals("64"))
{
  //do some logic
}
```